# Usability testing analysis

Tags: usability, usability-testing, quantitative-analysis

I've seen some researchers "behavioural analysis matrix" when analysing user testing sessions, they have participants at the top and tasks at the bottom and simply tick yes/no if participants complete the task.

I want to know more about this type of analysis but not sure where i can find reading material.

Comment: What would you like to know about this type of analysis? It is really just a visual way of presenting the results in a clear to understand format. This can be applied not just to usability testing but other types of data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is what you're asking, but if I were looking to analyse usability testing quantitatively I'd be considering things like:

- Task completion rate %
- Direct / indirect completion (navigation errors)
- Misclick rate
- Time on task

You can also capture things like satisfaction quantitatively.

Comment: And jot down where things go horribly wrong during the session: so you can ask users about it while you still have them in the building, and its fresh in their minds.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on [guerilla user testing](https://userbrain.net/blog/7-step-guide-guerrilla-usability-testing-diy-usability-testing-method); the matrix you describe is mentioned in Step 6.

Answer (score 0):

Foremost, we always test hypotheses. Each task contains 10 to 20 different hypotheses. It is very important, because this is how you can measure and compare the results of the usability test for prioritization. For example, 4 out of 5 participants were not able to perform something, then it is a critical issue, so you have to do something about it. The best scenario if everyone was able to perform the task as it was expected. That means, your design is correct.

Typical hypotheses:
(The participant) understands that ...
(The participant) will find that ...
(The participant) successfully complete that ...

For example, you have a form with plenty of parameters and the task is to fill some data and perform an action with the form. Usually, we add a hypotheses to each of the sections or essential elements. (e.g.: The participant understand that the date must be selected first in order to...)

Then we can measure the success/completion rate. If the participant was able to do it without any problem, then we add a 0 value to it. If it was not so obvious at the first try, but later they were able to perform it, we add 0,5 value to it. And when they were unable to perform it, we add 1 value. 5 participants, 3 of them were able to perform (3x0), 2 of them not (2x1) > 2/5 = 40% (0% everything is OK, 100% = critical). This way you can see what is the most critical part of your design because you can measure it. If there are no hypotheses, then the usability test is usually just a "world cloud" of feedbacks, and you cannot prioritize. This way you can see that the issue had happened only 1 out of 5 test or 5 out f 5 test.